# geoip_country_by_name returns empty string, no errors

Tags: php, geoip

I've followed a tutorial to setup geoip. I've uploaded the files to my server and here is my code:

```
<?php
    include_once('geoip.inc');
    $gi = geoip_open('GeoIP.dat', GEOIP_STANDARD);

    include_once('sql_conn.php');

    $sql = "SELECT ip,vid FROM views";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $ip = $row['ip'];
        $country = geoip_country_name_by_name($gi, $ip);
        echo $ip . " - " . $country . "<br />";
    } 

    geoip_close($gi);
?>
```

I'm trying to get the country by name by passing an IP address. My output is IE:

```
180.76.5.21 - 
162.222.182.156 - 
190.247.137.160 - 
190.247.137.160 - 
190.247.137.160 -
```

I'm not getting any errors or warnings from PHP.

EDIT:

As pointed out in the comments, the PHP manual says `geoip_country_name_by_name` expects only one argument, but this is what happens when I pass only the $ip to it:

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 for geoip_country_name_by_name(), called in /home/rlcoachi/public_html/admin/update_db.php on line 12 and defined in /home/rlcoachi/public_html/admin/geoip.inc on line 448
90.221.27.198 -
```

Comment: `string geoip_country_name_by_name ( string $hostname )` Only expects on param ([Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-country-name-by-name.php))

Comment: @Darren That's what I saw on the manual as well surprisingly, my tutorial however says the contrary and trying to pass only $hostname to the function, PHP tells me "expecting second argument"

Comment: That is funky. I'll check out the Api now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've narrowed down the issue. You're trying to use `geoip_country_name_by_name()` which, via MaxMinds GeoIP Api expects a name (i.e a hostname).
What you most likely want to try, is something like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $ip = $row['ip'];
    $country = geoip_country_name_by_addr($gi, $ip);
    echo $ip . " - " . $country . "<br />";
}
```

Using [`get_country_name_by_addr()`](https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-php#usage) instead, as you want to pass the IP Address and not a host name.

Comment: From the [PHP documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.geoip-country-code-by-name.php): 

`string geoip_country_code_by_name ( string $hostname )`
`hostname` The hostname or IP address whose location is to be looked-up.